# C# - XML serialize a complex class as only its primitive type

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Is it possible to take a complex class "A", which represents a primitive type with added information - such as valid values for that primitive , include an instance of "A" in "B", and XML serialize "B" with "A" appearing only as its primitive type?

```
Class A<T> {
  T obj;
  Static  ValidValue<T>[] validValues;
}

Class B {
  A<int> intVal;
  A<string> stringVal;
}
```

Desired output is just the primitives.  The ValidValues would be used to validate the data after deserialization:

```
  <B>
    <A>1</A>
    <A>example</A>
  </B>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to use property?

```
public class B {
  private A<int> intVal;
  public int IntVal{
    get{
      return intVal.obj;
    }
    set{
      intVal.obj = value;
    }
  }

  // same for stringval
}
```

As far as I know xmlserializer will only serialize public properties. So it should work.

I may misunderstood your requirement though.

Comment: This will work.  However, I would like to encapsulate this behavior so I don't need a Property and a Field for each variable in the class.

Comment: Not sure about the automated mapping though. Haven't tried it. For me, the simplest design are the best

Comment: This ended being the most economical thing to do.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do with [`DataContracts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx).

You just need to put a `[DataContract]` attribute on the class, and then decorate *only* the fields or properties that you want to be serialised with a `[DataMember]` attribute. You can serialise private fields in this way.

[See here for how to serialize such a decorated class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752244.aspx).

This is opt-in, i.e. only the items that you decorate with `[DataMember]` will be serialised.

For example ([from the MSDN sample here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733811.aspx)):

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    // This member is serialized.
    [DataMember]
    internal string FullName;

    // This is serialized even though it is private.
    [DataMember]
    private int Age;

    // This is not serialized because the DataMemberAttribute 
    // has not been applied.
    private string MailingAddress;

    // This is not serialized, but the property is.
    private string telephoneNumberValue;

    [DataMember]
    public string TelephoneNumber
    {
        get { return telephoneNumberValue; }
        set { telephoneNumberValue = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom serialization to control what variables are serialized.  You could then send whatever value you want to the serialized object.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: The question was about xml serialisation